# Python interpolation methods that accept generator expressions?

Tags: python, arrays, memory, generator, interpolation

So I have a large set of N arrays, each of length N_pix. I would like to interpolate between all the arrays (i.e. perform N_pix interpolations, each with N data points), in Python.

The problem is that each array is very large (can be up to 100sMB each, with 100s of arrays), and so I would like to be avoid reading all of them into memory.

My initial though was to use a generator expression to read large files one by one, and pass that generator to a interpolation routine:

```
def read_data_from_disc(paths):
    # Cycle through paths, and yield each large array 
    for path in paths: 
        yield np.loadtxt(path)

def interpolation(xs, paths):
    # Iterable returns large arrays one by one. 
    iterable = read_data_from_disc(paths)
    # Use some interpolation routine that can handle an 
    # iterable and interpolate iterable over 1d array, xs.
    spline = interpolator(xs, iterable, axis=0)
    return spline
```

However, I have been unsuccessful in finding any such `interpolator`. I am not familiar with the details of implementation of e.g. `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` or `scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline` (which are what I usually use), so perhaps what I am asking is not really possible. If this is the case can anyone suggest an alternative approach such that I do not have to read all of these arrays into memory at the same time?

Comment: if the data points are unformly spaced along one axis then there are digital signal processing/filter options for upsampling or sample rate conversion

Answer (score 0):

Your should loop over your `iterable`, producing the arrays one by one. That is, do something like

```
def interpolation(xs, paths):
    iterable = read_data_from_disc(paths)
    splines = [interpolator(xs, array, axis=0) for array in iterable]
    return splines
```

Now the `interpolation` function will return a list of all the splines, which is what I suspect is your intent with your example code. If the `interpolator` function does not store the array data after the creation of the spline object, you will have completed your goal of not keeping all the arrays in memory simultaneously.

Comment: I don't think I made my intent clear enough. I wish to interpolate along between the same element in each array. In my example then `len(xs)` = `N`, the number of arrays. In your example, `len(xs)`=`N_pix`, i.e. you are interpolating along each array separately.

Comment: So each element `i` of all arrays should have its own spline? That is, each spline needs data from all of the arrays? In that case you will have to have all arrays in memory simultanhusly. Alternatively, find a way to only read in the part of the arrays needed for the `i`th spline, do the `i`th spline, `del`ete the array data and read in the next parts and repeat.

Comment: Yes that is the required outcome. Okay, I had thought it might be the case. I don't think it will be possible to only read in part of the data - I will think about it more.